# MongoDB 3 (text search) or Elasticsearch?

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch

MongoDB 3 offers us text indexes (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-text/). My question is, should I use Elasticsearch or MongoDB 3 with the text index feature? Which is the best for searching through lots of entries? Which is the one with the best performance (5 million+ entries) in 2015?

I googled for this information, but I only found out-dated answers.

Thanks a lot!

**EDIT:** My use case is searching titles, descriptions and profiles for keywords. Is MongoDB 3 capable of searching these things with the text index feature (as fast or close to) like Elasticsearch?

Comment: spoiler : I'm an Elasticsearch fanatic. If you are looking for full-text search, I'd advice you to use Elasticsearch. But both Mongodb and Elasticsearch a scalable, so whether you have 5m+ or 20m+...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on what your use case is. If you want full text search capabilities like finding a document based on keywords, or finding a product based on keywords that may be present in title, description, review or tags of the product. If such is the use case elastic search is the thing to go for.

You may also want to evaluate Lucene/ Solr for above use cases.